# Android Studio how to show System Volume change in my seekBar?

Tags: android, volume, seekbar

In my app I can control system volume by changing seekBar. How to do it in the  opposite way, so that when I change system volume with pressing physical button on my device I see the change in my seekBar??

Sorry but I don't see answer for my question in other topics or maybe don't understand it. Everything works but only in one way. Moving SeekBar changes System Volume.
But changing System Volume doesn't change SeekBar position.
This is my code below:

```
volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekVolume);
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
    volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

    volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,progress,AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't see answer for my question in other topicis or maybe don't understand it. 
All topics shows how to do it in one way: moving SeekBar changes System Volume. But no topic shows how to do in the opposite, so that pressing device button of System Volume changes SeekBar position.